# external css ( how to align images horizontally with articles )

Tags: html, css, image

I need to make all of these images align within the article element and i cant seem to get it right

```html
<section>
<div id="imagesMain">
 <article id="art1">
  <img src="C:\Users\edwards\Dropbox\Fay-yaadh Edwards-52036\Web Development Essentials\Task 5\images/ITPic.jpg" class="articlePics" alt="InformationTechnology" />
  <h2 class="articleHeadings">Information Technology</h2>
  <p>simple computer stuff</p>
  <a href="" class="moreButton">More</a>
 </article>
 <article id="art2">
  <img src="C:\Users\edwards\Dropbox\Fay-yaadh Edwards-52036\Web Development Essentials\Task 5\images/Biology.jpg" class="articlePics" alt="biology" />
  <h2 class="articleHeadings">Biology</h2>
  <p>My overview</p>
  <a href="" class="moreButton">More</a>
 </article>
 <article id="art3">
  <img src="C:\Users\edwards\Dropbox\Fay-yaadh Edwards-52036\Web Development Essentials\Task 5\images/history.jpg" class="articlePics" alt="History" />
  <h2 class="articleHeadings">History</h2>
  <p>My overview</p>
  <a href="" class="moreButton">More</a>
 </article>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you include the CSS you've tried so far?

Comment: *align within the article element* - What do you mean?

Comment: So i need all three images to sit in a row next to each other, part of the task is keep the images within the article element, which doesnt seem to be working for me

Comment: @jeh   * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}

/* Clearfix (clear floats) */
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

Answer (score 0):

this should get you started.  Use flexbox for this type of thing.

```html
<section>
        <div id="imagesMain">
            <article id="art1" style="display:flex;justify-content:space-evenly;align-items:center;width:100%">
                <img   src="C:\Users\edwards\Dropbox\Fay-yaadh Edwards-52036\Web Development Essentials\Task 5\images/ITPic.jpg" class="articlePics" alt="InfoTech" />
                <h2   class="articleHeadings">Information Technology</h2>
             </article>   
                <p>simple computer stuff</p>
                <a href="" class="moreButton">More</a>
            
            <article style="display:flex;justify-content:space-evenly;align-items:center;width:100%" id="art2">
                <img src="C:\Users\edwards\Dropbox\Fay-yaadh Edwards-52036\Web Development Essentials\Task 5\images/Biology.jpg" class="articlePics" alt="biology" />
                <h2 class="articleHeadings">Biology</h2>
                </article>
                <p>My overview</p>
                <a href="" class="moreButton">More</a>
            
            <article style="display:flex;justify-content:space-evenly;align-items:center;width:100%"  id="art3">
                <img src="C:\Users\edwards\Dropbox\Fay-yaadh Edwards-52036\Web Development Essentials\Task 5\images/history.jpg" class="articlePics" alt="History" />
                <h2 class="articleHeadings">History</h2>
                </article>
                <p>My overview</p>
                <a href="" class="moreButton">More</a>
            
        </div>
    </section>
```